# Can you set up Azure portal with MFA

Tags: azure

In AWS I was able to set up MFA so that when I log into the console I have to enter an MFA code from my phone in addition to a password?

Is there a way to set MFA for https://portal.azure.com?

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you are looking for [**Azure Multi-Factor Authentication**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/multi-factor-authentication/).

> **Add protection for Azure administrator accounts**
>
> Multi-Factor Authentication adds a layer of security to your Azure administrator account at no additional cost. When it's turned on, you need to confirm your identity to spin up a virtual machine, manage storage, or use other Azure services.

Azure Multi-Factor Authentication is Microsoft's two-step verification solution.

It helps safeguard access to data and applications while meeting user demand for a simple sign-in process. It delivers authentication via a range of verification methods, including phone call, text message, or mobile app verification.

**Azure Multi-Factor Authentication in the cloud**

- Enable Azure Multi-Factor Authentication
- Turn on two-step verification for users

You could get start with it in the cloud by this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-cloud).

Comment: @Erick If it's helpful, you could mark it as answer, thanks.